# Regex(javascript), Debugger, Regex101

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to understand behavior of [Regex101](http://regex101.com) debugger, This is the [regex link](http://regex101.com/r/gQ6rT3), So if you activate the debugger and take a look from line 45, You can see the following behavior:

1. Line 45 the engine is watching the $ sign and understand that the end of the string haven't reached yet, So it need to subtract the string.
2. My problem is with lines (46,48,50,52,54), I try to understand why the engine is go from the $ sign (line 45) inside the subpattern(line 46) when the actual subtraction is done when the engine is on the $ sign, The way i see it is that 46,48,50,52,54 are wasted lines i can't understand their contribution, I mean why should i go inside the subpattern when the change happen when the engine on the $ sign to check if the string was end.

If anyone can help me with that i will be very thankful.

**Update:**

The regex:

```
<\/span>((?:(?!<\/span>)[\s\S])+)$
```

The string:

```
string</span>string</span>string</span>theStringIWant
```

Comment: I can't see that link with my outdated browser. Can you post the regex instead of people having to contend with an obstical.

Comment: I have seen several strange behaviours with regex101 debugger, I think that this debugger is buggy, It is better to test with regexbuddy.

Comment: Is there a free version for regexbuddy or similar software for free?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Whats wrong with my debugger? It does exactly what its supposed to. The lines mentioned by Aviel are lines where the engine is asserting positions for a continued match. The result you see on regex101 are 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work. Have you used the Raw regex at that web site?
There should be no options selected, ie: no multi-line or global or anything.

```
 #  Delimited:      /<\/span>((?:(?!<\/span>)[\s\S])+)$/
 #  Raw:             </span>((?:(?!</span>)[\s\S])+)$   

 </span>
 (
      (?:
           (?! </span> )
           [\s\S] 
      )+
 )
 $
```

Perl test case -

```
if ( "string</span>string</span>string</span>theStrngIWant" =~ /<\/span>((?:(?!<\/span>)[\s\S])+)$/)
{
    print "found: '$1'\n";
}
```

Output >>

```
found: 'theStrngIWant'
```